# Difference between Class<T> and reflect.TypeToken

Tags: java

I have the two code snippets that do exactly the same thing.
If you can use Class then what scenarios would you use TypeToken?

```
public static <T> List<T> readJsonArray(String filename, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    JavaType listType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, clazz);
    return objectMapper.readValue(loadFile(filename), listType);
  }
```

and the following code:

```
public static <T> List<T> readJsonArray(String filename, TypeToken<T> typeToken) throws IOException {
    JavaType listType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, typeToken.getRawType());
    return objectMapper.readValue(loadFile(filename), listType);
  }
```

Comment: In this particular case or in general? Because `TypeToken.getRawType` returns a `Class` object, so these calls are idempotent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a big hint to this in the [Javadoc of `TypeToken`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)

> Represents a generic type T. Java doesn't yet provide a way to
>   represent generic types, so this class does.

What they mean to say with this sentence and the subsequent information is:

If `T` is a generic type (such a `java.util.List`), then `Class<T>` doesn't contain enough information about the generic type parameter. You can find out from `Class<List>` that it represents a `List`, but there is no way to find out from `Class<List>` that it represents a List of particular type like `List<String>`. You can't write `List<String>.class` in Java, it's rejected by the compiler.

A `TypeToken` does contain the information about the generic type parameters of a generic type.

Comment: Thanks Erwin that was a fantastic answer.